# Can jquery traverse the entire DOM and find the word Update in a href

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Seems that people are clicking on Enter key on board and while I can disable that I have business analysts wanting me to have the Enter key "click" the Update link

Since this is asp.net gridview I don't have a lot of control of it plus there are many rows in which the __doPostBack data is different

How can I detect the word "Update"  ( it was "Edit" along with many other rows having that Edit link as well)

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;GridView1$_ctl2$_ctl0&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Update</a>
```

**Update:**

I want to find a keyword in an href that is in a table.

So "Update" is the keyword that is in href which is in a

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
          <a href..>Update</a>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**Update 2:**

Here is a Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/bthorn/vzjLzfck/

I believe that this does FIND if update is there

```
 var y = $('a').filter(function(index) { return $(this).text() === "Update"; });

 I changed Update to "Updated" and length went from 1 to 0 ....
```

**So then if that is working, I want to then proceed to have that Link executed or whatever do that essentially It is like someone is clicking on that href link**

**Final working code**

```
$(document).keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {

            $("a").each(function () {

                $("a").filter(function () {
                    var s = $(this).text() === "Update";

                    if (s == true) {
                        //console.log('yes in');
                        this.click();
                    }

                });


                return false;
            });

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I do not have experience with GridViews but if you want to get all 'a' tags which contain the text Update you can do $('a:contains("Update")') or an exact match $('a').filter(function(index) { return $(this).text() === "Update"; }).

Comment: So "Update" is in the href attribute?

Comment: Let me know if I misunderstood your question but if "Update" is going to be in the href attribute you can change the filter to be: $('a').filter(function(index) { return $(this).attr('href').indexOf("Update") > -1 })

Comment: Yes,  I think that your second "exact match" might just work  I'm going to Edit my question again to paste a jsfiddle along with asking question   thx in advance and please then plan on adding an answer so then I can end up giving you the point credit etc...

Comment: console.log   i can see    href: "javascript:__doPostBack('GridView1$_ctl2$_ctl0','')"

Comment: I assumed that your GridView will have multiple rows. So when the user hits Enter which row do you plan on Updating (assuming that there are multiple rows with Update text)? If there is only one row with Update then you just need to get the element and call .click() on it

Comment: How do i just get that element and call .click() on it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to target any `href` that contains the word "Update" you can use jQuery's [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function on the `href`

```
$("a").filter(function(){
    return $(this).attr('href').indexOf("Update");
});
```

If you want the text to contain "Update" you can use:

```
 $("a").filter(function(){
    return $(this).text() === "Update";
 });
```

Comment: How do these get detected?  How can it execute the href?

Comment: Are you able to determine which GridView row had focus when Enter was hit? Because if you know the row you can just target the link and click it $(row).find('a').filter(return $(this).text() === "Update";).click();

Comment: I don't know what row, but it seems that href: "javascript:__doPostBack('GridView1$_ctl2$_ctl0','')"   is what is showing up on jsfiddle console windows when clicking on the submit button which is essentially showing your  var y = $('a').filter(function(index) { return $(this).text() === "Update"; });

Comment: Only one row will have Update, so how can I call .click() on it?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("body").on("keypress", function(e) {
    if(e.which != 13) {
       return;
    };
    $("a").each(function() {
        var link = $(this);
        if(link.text() == "Update") {
            console.log("woot");
            window.open(link.attr("href"));
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't think it knows about this.text  even though the code seems logical

Comment: I see the fiddle working, but <a href="other.aspx">Callout</a>  is what is happening on my code when I do a console.log(this);

Comment: you could try doing   `if($(this).text() == "Update")` or `if($(this).html() == "Update")` instead